# Подскажите программу для замены белого фона на фото на изображение?

Tags: photoshop, watermark

Есть очень много фотографий с обувью на белом фоне, я хочу быстро заменять белый фон на изображение со своим логотипом.

Есть ли какая-то специальная программа для этого или как это сделать в Фотошопе? Что-то на подобие ЗАМЕНИТЬ ЦВЕТ в Фотошопе, только заменить на картинку, а не на другой цвет.

Comment: Это сайт программистов, так что c использованием OpenCV или другой библиотеки для обработки изображений создаёте маску по белому цвету, и потом отрисовываете свой фон с применением маски.

Answer (score 0):

Довольно просто сделатьтакую массовую замену при помощи [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php).

Это - навороченная консольная утилита, которой при помощи ключей и командных файлов можно "объяснить" много вещей, котрые можно сделать с изображениями.

Классически она применяется для массового изменения размеров, конвертации из формата в формат и т.п.

Програма существует как для линукса, так и для винды.

Конкретный пример добавления ватермарка есть в этой [статье](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/imagemagick-watermark/)

Но в комментариях правильно намекают, что это "путь для слабаков": можно написать свою реализацию добавления логотипа. В принципе, это не сложно: если открыть два изображения, привести их к одному размеру, сконвертировать в bmp - то в памяти компа это будут просто два двуменых массива. Вы можете потом "сложить" их, или делать более сложную логику - например, рисовать логотип строго на белом фоне, чтобы он не портил фото.

Comment: Я установил программу, но не могу понять как сделать то, что мне нужно...

Comment: А ссылка на статью, которая в моём ответе и показывает, как надо вставлять ватермарк - вам не помогла?

Comment: если ссылка не помогла - Вы напишите, может, кто то еще что то посоветует...